# What is the best way to handle social login and app login both?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth

In my app, I want both social and app login. What is the best way to handle this with a single User table?
Should I change these allowNull fields to true? because I cannot get the password,phone,address etc of a user who signed-up in my app using Gmail,Facebook etc
My current user model looks like this:

```
{
      firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: { isEmail: true },
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      role: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        defaultValue: "Customer",
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          isIn: [["Super-Admin", "Admin", "Sub-Admin", "Customer"]],
        },
      },
      phone: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      address: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      isConfirm: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
```